# Углубленное изучение программирования

Tags: c++, objective-c

Интересует углубленное изучение программирования.
Посоветуйте хорошую школу программирования в Киеве.
Интересуют С-подобные языки.
Благодарю.

Comment: Книжки! Книжки, и ещё раз книжки. Медленно, вдумчиво читать. Делать собственный проект, показывать другим, реагировать на критику, улучшать. Практиковаться.

Других путей человечество не изобрело.

---
В Киеве пойдите на кружок при 145-ой школе, УФМЛ или «Лидере», там научат.

Comment: @VladD, почему только книжки, а документация? Истинный дзен я считаю можно познать только из документации и/или спецификации.

Comment: @Lucky, в документации редко встретишь описание хаков и язык там часто бывает слишком сухой для новичка. Но дзен да, именно там.

Comment: Кроме этого хороший чужой код стоит почитать и сделать себе библиотечку (возможно просто набор образцов (не рискую использовать термин шаблон) исходного кода)  из понравившихся фрагментов.

Comment: >почему только книжки, а документация?

ну все же документация предназначена не для обучения как такового, а для справочных целей. У документации обычно совершенно другой формат, не очень удобный для обучения. Это что-то вроде изучения языка по словарю